# Installing Node.js v14 on docker container doesn't work

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

Here is the Docker file
[image]

[image]

After this part, it says an error.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to use a ready-to-go docker image with Node.js?

Comment: You seem to have included two PNG images in place of the Dockerfile.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including a complete runnable Dockerfile and the error output, as text and not images?

Comment: Three problems with this question.  1) Images instead of text.  2) The FROM directive of your dockerfile is the most important part and you haven't disclosed it.  Thus you haven't provided a minimal reproducible example.  3)  You claim you got an error but you don't disclose what the error is.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73693701/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install node 14 on a docker php:8.1fpm image, I found a code that uses nvm instead of direct install, for me it was very helpful:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.21.1
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR && curl -s -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
RUN . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default
```